# Friend B and C have eaten zero apples. How many more apples has C eaten?

Tags: infinity

Friend $A$ claims that he has eaten $1$ apple today.

Friend $B$ responds. Congrats, I have eaten $0$ apples, so that is $\infty$ more apples than me.

Friend $C$ says, but I have also eaten $0$ apples. So how many times more than you have I done? $0$ or $\infty$?

Comment: How is friend $B$ correct?  Friend $A$ only ate *one* more apple than friend $B$, not infinitely more.  We are only dealing with finite quantities here...

Comment: haha good point @user46944

Comment: What is this, are you trying to say $1/0=\infty$, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: In general, $0\cdot\infty$ is indeterminate, not equal to $1$.  The challenge/problem with this type of question is that one cannot treat $\infty$ as a number.  I would say that $B$ has eaten $n$ times more apples than $C$ where $n$ is any number.

Comment: A has eaten infinitely as many apples as B has eaten, in the sense that for any finite number x A has eaten more than x times as many apples as B as eaten. But C has eaten the same amount of apples as B and at the same time 10 times as many apples as B, because 10*0 is 0 obviously.

Comment: Its simply all statements: C has eaten x times as many apples as B are true, since both C and B have eaten 0 apples. In the strict sense C has eaten infinitely many times as many apples as B is false, since "infinitely as many" would mean "there is no finite number x so that C has eaten x times as many apples as B".

Comment: @user46944 A has not eaten 2 more apples than B. There is a difference between saying I have eaten 2 times as many apples as you and I have eaten 2 more apples than you.

Comment: @s.harp OP wrote that friend $B$ said friend $A$ ate infinitely more apples than $B$.

Comment: @user46944 Indeed that is right. I have assumed that to be an error in formulation since otherwise the statements are obviously incorrect.